# R : Count unique element per interval

Tags: r, performance, intervals, genomicranges

Let say I've a list of non-overlapping genomic intervals.

```
chr1    1   100
chr1    101 200
chr1    201 300
chr1    301 400
```

and a list of genomic positions linked to different samples as :

```
chr1    50  sampleA
chr1    60  sampleB
chr1    110 sampleA
chr1    130 sampleB
chr1    160 sampleA
chr1    190 sampleC
chr1    350 sampleB
chr1    360 sampleB
```

My goal is to count the number of unique samples for each interval. In my real dataset the interval table is ~400.000 lines and the genomic position-sample table is ~30.000 lines.

This calculation is embedded in a simulation thus it should be as fast as possible. I already tried with GenomicRanges as :

```
require(GenomicRanges)
interval.gr <- GRanges(intervals$chr,IRanges(intervals$start,intervals$end))
positions.gr <- GRanges(positions$chr,IRanges(positions$pos,positions$pos))
ov <- findOverlaps(interval.gr,positions.gr)
intervals %>%
  slice(queryHits(ov)) %>%
  mutate(sample=positions$sample[subjectHits(ov)]) %>% 
  group_by(chr,start,end) %>% 
  summarise(n_sample=length(unique(sample)))
```

results in

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   chr, start [3]
  chr   start   end n_sample
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
1 chr1      1   100        2
2 chr1    101   200        3
3 chr1    301   400        1
```

However it still drop intervals without samples in it (201-300) and it is also not very fast. Using my dataset :

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    x 159.3901 161.621 190.1703 164.4879 168.3116 297.8395    10
```

I'm wondering if there is better and faster ways to do this kind of analysis ?

Thanks

---

reproducible datasets :

```
intervals <- data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1"),start=c(1,101,201,301),end=c(100,200,300,400))

positions <- data.frame(chr=rep("chr1",8),pos=c(50,60,110,130,160,190,350,360),sample=c("sampleA","sampleB","sampleA","sampleB","sampleA","sampleC","sampleB","sampleB"))
```

> edit

reproducible datasets with the same size as my real dataset

```
intervals <- data.frame(chr=paste0("chr",round(runif(400000,min = 1,max = 22))),start=round(runif(n = 400000,min = 1,max = 100000000)))
intervals$end <- intervals$start+100

positions <- data.frame(chr=paste0("chr",round(runif(30000,min = 1,max = 22))),pos=round(runif(n = 30000,min = 1,max = 100000000)),sample=sample(paste0("sample",1:400),size = 30000,replace=T))
```

Comment: One question about the real dataset, are all the intervals equally long (1 to 100, 101 to 200, etc.)?

Comment: @Jon : Yes same length. And non-overlapping

Comment: another small clarification, they start with 1 or the start can be random as on your second example?

Comment: in my real dataset it's indeed starting with 1 (for each chromosome)

Answer (score 2):

Building on what @Jon said, data.table is a great way to approach this.  Using the function foverlaps() greatly improves speed.

```
library(data.table)
intervals <- data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1"),
                        start=c(1,101,201,301),
                        end=c(100,200,300,400))

positions <- data.frame(chr=rep("chr1",8),
                        pos=c(50,60,110,130,160,190,350,360),
                        sample=c("sampleA","sampleB","sampleA","sampleB","sampleA","sampleC","sampleB","sampleB"))
setDT(positions)
setDT(intervals)

  positions[, pos_tmp := pos]
  setkey(positions,chr, pos, pos_tmp)
  overlap = foverlaps(intervals, positions, type="any",by.x=c("chr","start", "end")) ## return overlap indices
  overlap[!is.na(sample),.(n_sample = .N), by = .(chr, start, end)]
```

Compared to @Jon's implementation which takes ~6 seconds on my machine, the above implementation takes ~180 milliseconds

Comment: Hi @Bryan. It's indeed very fast ! thanks. However how can I keep the intervals with 0 samples ?

Comment: @Bryan the foverlaps approach is really good!  n_sample = .N can generate issues if there are sample duplicates. You should use length(unique())

Comment: @Jon good point the above sample would count a sample for each pos value it has, if you want a count of distinct samples data.table has a nice built-in for length(unique()) called uniqueN() here's an example of it with request for empty groups `overlap[,.(n_sample = uniqueN(sample[!is.na(sample)])), by = .(chr, start, end)] `

Answer (score 0):

For a large sample I'd try to use a non-equi  join in `data.table`.
The benchmark in the sample is worse than tmfmnk's answer but for abigger dataset it will likely have a smaller memory footprint and be faster.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

intervals <-
  data.table(
    chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"),
    start = c(1, 101, 201, 301),
    end = c(100, 200, 300, 400)
  )
positions <-
  data.table(
    chr = rep("chr1", 8),
    pos = c(50, 60, 110, 130, 160, 190, 350, 360),
    sample = c(
      "sampleA",
      "sampleB",
      "sampleA",
      "sampleB",
      "sampleA",
      "sampleC",
      "sampleB",
      "sampleB"
    )
  )


# This takes only the ones we need:
positions[intervals, on = .(chr == chr, pos <= end, pos >= start), .(
  chr = i.chr,
  start = i.start,
  end = i.end,
  sample = x.sample
)][, .(n_sample = sum(uniqueN(sample, na.rm = TRUE))), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]


# Benchmarking
microbenchmark(positions[intervals, on = .(chr == chr, pos <= end, pos >= start), .(
  chr = i.chr,
  start = i.start,
  end = i.end,
  sample = x.sample
)][, .(n_sample = sum(uniqueN(sample, na.rm = TRUE))), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]
, times = 50)
```

Let me know if it does the work.
I included a few changes to create a example closer to your use case. 
Also included Bryan's case for benchmarking. Still your approach is the fastest. I had hopes in the 4th approach (only 2 keys) but it still is slower.

```r
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(GenomicRanges)
set.seed(14)
intervals <-
    data.table(chr = paste0("chr", round(runif(
        400000, min = 1, max = 22
    ))), start = round(runif(
        n = 400000, min = 1, max = 100000000
    )))
# modified to start always with 1
intervals[, start := floor(start / 100) * 100 + 1L]

intervals$end <- intervals$start + 100L

# erase duplicates
intervals <-
    unique(intervals[, .SD, .SDcols = c("chr", "start", "end")])

positions <-
    data.table(
        chr = paste0("chr", round(runif(
            30000, min = 1, max = 22
        ))),
        pos = round(runif(
            n = 30000, min = 1, max = 100000000
        )),
        sample = sample(paste0("sample", 1:400), size = 30000, replace = T)
    )

setkeyv(intervals, c("chr", "start", "end"))
positions[, pos2 := pos]
setkeyv(positions, c("chr", "pos", "pos2"))


microbenchmark({
    interval.gr <-
        GRanges(intervals$chr, IRanges(intervals$start, intervals$end))
    positions.gr <-
        GRanges(positions$chr, IRanges(positions$pos, positions$pos))
    ov <- findOverlaps(interval.gr, positions.gr)
    res1 <- intervals %>%
        slice(queryHits(ov)) %>%
        mutate(sample = positions$sample[subjectHits(ov)]) %>%
        group_by(chr, start, end) %>%
        summarise(n_sample = length(unique(sample))) %>% data.table(.)

    intervals_1 <-
        rbind(res1, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]
}, times = 50)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 expr
#>  {     interval.gr <- GRanges(intervals$chr, IRanges(intervals$start,          intervals$end))     positions.gr <- GRanges(positions$chr, IRanges(positions$pos,          positions$pos))     ov <- findOverlaps(interval.gr, positions.gr)     res1 <- intervals %>% slice(queryHits(ov)) %>% mutate(sample = positions$sample[subjectHits(ov)]) %>%          group_by(chr, start, end) %>% summarise(n_sample = length(unique(sample))) %>%          data.table(.)     intervals_1 <- rbind(res1, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample,          na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")] }
#>       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  148.0612 164.4884 225.8665 178.5495 219.6038 585.5995    50


microbenchmark({
    # This takes only the ones we need:
    res2 <-
        positions[intervals, on = .(chr == chr, pos <= end, pos >= start), nomatch = 0L, .(
            chr = i.chr,
            start = i.start,
            end = i.end,
            sample = x.sample
        )][, .(n_sample = length(unique(sample, na.rm = TRUE))), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]
    intervals_2 <-
        rbind(res2, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]

}, times = 50)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             expr
#>  {     res2 <- positions[intervals, on = .(chr == chr, pos <= end,          pos >= start), nomatch = 0L, .(chr = i.chr, start = i.start,          end = i.end, sample = x.sample)][, .(n_sample = length(unique(sample,          na.rm = TRUE))), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]     intervals_2 <- rbind(res2, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample,          na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")] }
#>       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  294.4081 338.0309 447.0925 383.2813 548.3734 883.4389    50

microbenchmark({
    # Bryan's approach
    overlap = foverlaps(intervals,
                        positions,
                        type = "any",
                        by.x = c("chr", "start", "end")) ## return overlap indices
    res3 <-
        overlap[!is.na(sample), .(n_sample = length(unique(sample))), by = .(chr, start, end)]
    intervals_3 <-
        rbind(res3, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")]

}, times = 50)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 expr
#>  {     overlap = foverlaps(intervals, positions, type = "any", by.x = c("chr",          "start", "end"))     res3 <- overlap[!is.na(sample), .(n_sample = length(unique(sample))),          by = .(chr, start, end)]     intervals_3 <- rbind(res3, intervals, fill = TRUE)[, sum(n_sample,          na.rm = TRUE), by = c("chr", "start", "end")] }
#>      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  221.907 280.8795 429.961 398.0075 475.0276 1017.866    50


## Starting by 1

set.seed(14)
intervals <-
    data.table(chr = paste0("chr", round(runif(
        400000, min = 1, max = 22
    ))), start = round(runif(
        n = 400000, min = 1, max = 100000000
    )))
# modified to start always with 1
intervals[, start := floor(start / 100) * 100 + 1L]


positions[, start := floor(pos / 100) * 100 + 1L]
positions <-
    unique(positions[, .SD, .SDcols = c("chr", "start", "sample")])
setkeyv(intervals, c("chr", "start"))
setkeyv(positions, c("chr", "start"))
microbenchmark({
    intervals_4 <-
        positions[intervals][, .(n_sample = sum(!is.na(sample))), by = c("chr", "start")]#
    # add end
    intervals_4[, end := start + 100L]
}, times = 50)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                                                                                          expr
#>  {     intervals_4 <- positions[intervals][, .(n_sample = sum(!is.na(sample))),          by = c("chr", "start")]     intervals_4[, `:=`(end, start + 100L)] }
#>       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  419.1001 443.9567 546.0186 478.5985 650.4682 1115.179    50
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you @Jon. I tried your solution. It's indeed faster on the test dataset but not on the real dataset (my solution is still the fastest one). I will edit my question to add a simulated dataset with the same size as the real dataset. It will be easier for benchmarking.

Comment: or simpler: `positons[, c("start", "end") := .(pos, pos)][intervals, on=.(chr, start>=start, end<=end), .N, by=.EACHI, nomatch=0L]` should work I think ...